# Blazor - WebAssemby ASP.NET Core hosted model

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

There seems to be little documentation on the new WebAssembly ASP.NET Core hosted model.  I realise that Blazer WebAssembly model is in preview until May 2020, however, once the [latest preview template](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-1-release-now-available/) is installed in Visual Studio 2019, there is the option to use ASP.NET Core hosted.

[image]

From what I can gather, this model appears to be a hybrid between the Blazor Server App and the Blazor WebAssembly App hosting models in that in addition to using the client to render in WebAssembly, also employs server technology, e.g. SignalR.

What would be the benefits of using this hosting model?

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the benefits of using this hosting model?

In the hosted model, the server will:

- serve the client (wasm) Blazor application
- typically provide APIs that will be consumed by the client application

In the hosted model, you do not need SignalR to get the Blazor app working